# Error using svg with webpack and storybook

Tags: react-native, svg, webpack, storybook

When using svg with webpack and storybook, I get this error.

[Error in storybook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buj7H.png)

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource.js 18:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| const AssetSourceResolver = require('./AssetSourceResolver');
|

> import type {ResolvedAssetSource} from './AssetSourceResolver';
> |
> | let _customSourceTransformer, _serverURL, _scriptURL;

I have tried to install by: npm i react-native-svg-web, and add this to webpack config : [Added line in webpack.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGl3C.png)

```
module.exports = async ({ config }) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
      'react-native-svg': 'react-native-svg-web'
    };
```

Is it a valid import, for webpack, or has anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

In the webpack.config.js file, adding the following line fixed it for me:

```
module.exports = ({config}) => {
  // ...
  config.resolve.extensions.unshift('.web.js'); // added this line
  // ...
  return config;
};
```

The reason for this is described [here](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/issues/1553#issuecomment-804089936).